# Jetpack Compose - long press propagation from child to parent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, gesture-recognition

I have a parent layout with couple of children and I have a long click listener on the parent and couple of children have it's own regular click listeners. I want to achieve a behavior when I long press any of the child and if this event is not consumed the parent Composable would receive the callback. Is it possible? I know I can pass the onLongClick callback down to all the children but I want to avoid a situation when new child will be added and someone forgets to add it. I would like to to this somehow automatically.

I've played with that and could not figure it out. Example code

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .combinedClickable(
            onLongClick = {
                Toast
                    .makeText(context, "Long click parent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            },
            onClick = {
                Toast
                    .makeText(context, "Normal click parent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
        )
        .padding(16.dp)
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(100.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.Green)
            .clickable {
                Toast
                    .makeText(context, "Normal click child", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
    )
}
```